# Rails: Get a model to name itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have three models, `houses`, `users` & `rooms`.

Rooms is a pretty boring model, it is mainly used to designate which room a user occupies within a house. Aside from associations it only has one record, name. Name is it's boring designation that the user can set eg. "funky smelling attic room" or just boring old "Room 1".

If the user doesn't attribute a name (and if the room doesn't have any occupants for me to do some smarter auto-naming), I want the model to name itself.

Specifically I want it to do: `Room #{i}` (eg Room 1, Room 320, Room 12321) whenever the user calls Room.new() without attributes.

The bit I'm having trouble with is how t make it so that `i` connected to the associated house. So there could be many called 'Room 1' but they would all have to be in different houses, within each house the `Room #{i}` would need to be a unique name...

I know to do some of this with validations (uniqueness) but how... and where, would I put an enumerator to count up the number of rooms already present in a house and do `i += 1` when it comes around to naming any new additions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to create an after_create callback in your `Room` model:

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :house
  after_create :name_room

  def name_room
    if name.blank?
      update_column(:name, default_name)
    end
  end

  def default_name
    "Room #{rooms_in_house} of house #{self.house.id}"
  end

  def rooms_in_house
    self.house.rooms.count
  end
end
```

Hopefully I understood your question and gave you something useful... but it looks like you might not even have to use the enumerable `count` block!

If number of rooms isn't correct then you can adjust it in `rooms_in_house` by just adding 1 in the method.

Comment: Of course, after_create! That's perfect! Thank you so much. Bonus question is it best practice to keep all of this on the model or if I end up doing a lot of validations/after_create/before_create is it best to spin this out into it's own set of model helpers?

Comment: I think it's best to keep callbacks in the model. I usually make those methods private and just keep them at the bottom. Makes debugging later easier if you ever need to. If another person were looking at your code they'd have to do a project search for `rooms_in_house` if you moved it. Also I think `helpers` can only be used in controllers... You could create a `concern` and include it in the class if you really wanted to move it out but abstracting the `rooms_in_house` would really only make sense if you expected to use the callback method in other classes so I would keep it in the model :)